# Page reloads when I use document.write(onClick) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php

I make a code for a basic calculator in PHP and I had to use JavaScript to show it on the screen. However, when I try to make any calculation in **Firefox**, the page reloads with blank code and only a 0 shows up.

In Google Chrome everything looks fine.

I tried put `document.open()` and `document.close()`, and this still works fine in Chrome, but nothing happens in Firefox.

Anybody have a solution for this?

This is my function:

```
<?php 
function calcular(){
  $n1 = isset($_POST["val1"])?$_POST["val1"]:0;
  $n2 = isset($_POST["val2"])?$_POST["val2"]:0;
  $op = isset($_POST["operacao"])?$_POST["operacao"]:1;

  switch ($op) {
    case 'subtracao':
      $res = $n1 - $n2;
      break;    

    case 'multiplicacao':
      $res = $n1 * $n2;
      break;

    case 'divisao':
      $res = $n1 / $n2;
      break;

    default:
      $res = $n1 + $n2;
      break;
  }

  echo $res;
}
?>
```

The code on the form:

```
<input type="text" name="resultado" value="<?php calcular(); ?>">
<input type="submit" name="botao" value="Calcular" onclick="document.open();document.write('<?php calcular(); ?>');document.close();">
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't mix PHP,HTML,JS like this...

Comment: Use `<input type="button" />` instead of submit

Comment: I really tried not to! I still don't know any other solutions...

Comment: or `return false` in the javascript call

Comment: I chanced for "button", now I have the same problem in Chrome ;;

Comment: If it works in Chrome, then something breaks before [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write). It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do, when it wipes the previous document away. Don't use `dW()`, use proper DOM manipulation method instead.

Comment: The `return false` didn't work too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript. Just keep your php function and this should work:

```
<?php
function calcular() {
    // your function...
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="val1"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="val2"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="operacao"></p>
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
<div>
    <?php calcular(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why I thought that I needed JavaScript here. Now my code worked just fine, I was just complicating everything! Thank you!